# Load text in to Label on text change event of RadTextBox in insert mode of RadGrid

Tags: telerik

I am using `RadGrid`.

In its Insert Mode.I have `RadTextBox` and `Label`.
So all I want to do is when I write into `RadTextBox` and Lost Focus of it. A function should be called upon that and that function retrieves data from database and assign it to Label inside that Insert Mode.

So I'm not able to access controls inside the Insert Mode.
How should I call a function on textchange event of `RadTextBox` and how do I access `Label` inside that Insert Mode and fetch some data and assign to it?

Comment: Have you tried using the GridEditManager? ((GridEditableItem)e.Item).EditManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code snippet.
Please add Jquery reference in your in project/page.

.js

```
  function ValueChanged(sender, eventArgs) {

            var newvalueoftextbox = eventArgs.get_newValue();

            var id = sender.get_id();
            id = id.replace("RadTextBox1", "Label1");
            var Label1 = $get(id);
            // your logic come here - get value from DB
            Label1.innerHTML = "Your Value";
        }
```

.aspx

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowCustomPaging="True"
        OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" GridLines="None" ShowGroupPanel="True"
        OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">
        <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server">
                        <ClientEvents OnValueChanged="ValueChanged" />
                        </telerik:RadTextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data = new[] {
            new { ID = 1, Name ="Name_1"},
            new { ID = 2, Name = "Name2"},
            new { ID = 3, Name = "Name3"},
            new { ID = 4, Name = "Name4"},
            new { ID = 5, Name = "Name5"}
        };
    RadGrid1.DataSource = data;
}
```